# Safely initializing a std::array of bools

Tags: c++, stdarray, zero-initialization, default-initialization

Given this array declaration and initialization:

```
std::array<bool, 20> invalid_params{};
```

Can I assume that all the elements in the array will **always** be initialized to false, or is it better to do it explicitly?

Comment: If you use the `{}` syntax, it's always initialized with `false`. If you don't use that, it's left uninitialized.

Comment: For built-in types, value-initialization is always similar to `=0` for all elements. (becoming `0`, `false`, `nullptr`, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's guaranteed to be filled with `false` values.

`std::array` is an aggregate, hence it has no user-defined constructors, hence [value-initializing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) it performs [zero-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

---

But if you remove `{}` (turning it into default-initialization), the elements will be uninitialized.

Comment: If it's defined in global scope its elements will be zero-initialized even without an explicit initializer.

Answer (score -1):

Documentation says: "default initialization may result in indeterminate values for non-class T". So, it seems that you can not assume that it will be initialized.

Comment: Default-initialization would be `std::array<bool, 20> invalid_params;`. With `{}` it's value-initialziation.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat To be fair, OP didn't specify in their question whether it is safe to assume that the elements would be false using only this syntax (which it is).